# Glassfish 4 hangs after some time

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish-4

I have glassfish 4 instance, and a simple java app with servlets on it (using mysql). After some time, server hangs, and I can't get any replay from it. After force restart from command line everything works fine for some time... I don't understand why is it going. Can anyone, please, help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redeploy an application, a new classloader is created for its and all classes of your application are loaded again. This consumes memory in the perm gen space.

To solve this problem

1. Increase memory (so that this problem don't come frequently ) by configuring "domain.xml" in `/glassfish/domain/domain1/config` search for `<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=` set it to higher value eg- 198m or 256m and so on.
2. Restart glassfish when you redeploy your application over 5 or 6 time.